# Convert array to controller laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $data = $request->all();
  dd($data);
}
```

**Result :** `{"name":"Joni","age":"18"}`

I want to convert it to an array ? give me ideas.Thanks

Comment: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: This is json result, you can use json_decode()

Comment: $request->all() already returns an array https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_all . What does the dd really show you?

Answer (score 0):

just `toArray()`

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $data = $request->toArray();
  dd($data);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->all(); returns array,  you don't need to convert.
```

You can check the type by using `gettype()`  function.

[Read More about request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input)

Hope this will be useful.